# Can someone tell me which sutra verse explains (by a sage) the way to proceed to meditate for 24 hours?

Tags: meditation

I have forgotten which sutra was it. But it says way to proceed for 24 hours meditation. (First same hours as relaxation and then relaxation hours are reduced.... Something like this. Please tell me which was it.